# How to pick the column dynamically based on month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need your help bring such a way the below format.. i am pretty must confused to bring the format dynamically every month,Because every month the column name has to be swap between MO or Adj_M0

If you see my example [image: Table structure and ouput format]

When you see the above format which i need for every month.
Ex: refer Ouput - Jan (Column Name) will swap compare to Ouput - Feb

Similar like it will swap the column on every month , so can you please guide me how to bring my output format.

Hope your understand,pls guide me or give me some sample code

Comment: What columns are in the table?  Table Structure does not show columns named Adj_M5, Adj_M6, Adj_M7, Adj_M8, Adj_M9 which appear in later months. How many month columns are in the Table?  Have you tried to  dynamically build SQL for each month? Show us that... tkx

Comment: Hi DonPablo, Sorry i missed the colum name in table structure.. however i have till Adj_M12 in my table

Answer (score 0):

So lets build the SQL dynamically each time it is run. Start with and then tune it to get your desired results --

```
Function fnMakeTheSQL(nMO As Long) As String

    ' define the output SQL string, and initialize it to blanks
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = ""

    ' concat the first part of the SQL
    sSQL = sSQL & " SELECT  "
    sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "   Name, "
    sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "   M0, "

    ' now the interesting part, the LOOPing to build Prior & This month-s columns
    Dim iMO As Long
    For iMO = 1 To nMO
        sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "   M" & iMO & ", "
    Next iMO

    ' and more interesting part, the LOOPing to build Future ADJ columns
    'Dim iMO As Long
    For iMO = nMO + 1 To 12
        sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "   ADJ_M" & iMO & ", "
    Next iMO

    ' strip off the trailing comma
    sSQL = Left(sSQL, InStrRev(sSQL, ",") - 1)

    ' concat the last part of the SQL
    sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "  From  yourTable "
    sSQL = sSQL & vbCrLf & "  Order By Name "

    ' give it back to the caller
    fnMakeTheSQL = sSQL

End Function
```

When the month is 5, the resulting SQL is --

```
SELECT  
Name, 
M0, 
M1, 
M2, 
M3, 
M4, 
M5, 
ADJ_M6, 
ADJ_M7, 
ADJ_M8, 
ADJ_M9, 
ADJ_M10, 
ADJ_M11, 
ADJ_M12
From  yourTable 
Order By Name
```

Comment: Thanks Don, is there any easier way to get the column instead of using function ? just asking

Comment: YES , This is what i am doing manually every month SELECT  
Name, 
M0, 
M1, 
M2, 
M3, 
M4, 
M5, 
ADJ_M6, 
ADJ_M7, 
ADJ_M8, 
ADJ_M9, 
ADJ_M10, 
ADJ_M11, 
ADJ_M12
From  yourTable 
Order By Name  -- There is no easier way don ?

Comment: I have added the resulting SQL when the month = 5.  You could use this function in your program (not in SP in server), and then Execute it from your program.  What's so hard about this way, that it needs to be easier?

Comment: Let me try don, however i need to use this script in SP only.., how will i use this function to get the column name in sp ? is there any way